# Unsycronized LinkedHashMap lead to memory leaks in multithreaded environment?

Tags: java, multithreading

I wonder following things

1. Doesn't a memory leak occur even if sycronized is not implemented in the `get method`?
2. If a memory leak occurs, what is the reason?

step1: put key : "a" -> value : "b"

step2: thread1 -> remove("a"), thread2 -> get("a") (occurs at the same time)

=> will the cache class still refer to "b"? can't "b" be garbage collected forever?

```
    class Cache {
        private Map<String, String> cache = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        public synchronized void put(String key, String value) {
            cache.put(key, value);
        }

        public synchronized void remove(String key) {
            cache.remove(key);
        }

        public String get(String key) {
            return cache.get(key);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think the `HashMap` would have a reference to b after `remove("a")` has been called?

Comment: It seems that the jvm needs to know that "b" is no longer referenced in the hashmap for garbage collection. I am not sure because the `get method` is not synchronized, but I am worried that there may be a problem with the reference.

Comment: A lack of synchronization causes, generally, much _weirder_ problems than simple memory leaks.  It's a _possible_ outcome, but certainly not guaranteed.

Comment: Adding new elements requires updates of a few to many thousands of instructions.  
 E.g. if the map determines it's too full, it rehashes all elements into a new map with more buckets.  Even a normal add or remove of a single element requires adjusting the self-balancing trees that implement the buckets.  If there's no thread synchronization, the read thread can preempt a write in the middle when the data structure is in an inconsistent state. Returned values may well be junk. An exception (like NPE) may occur. I can't see how a memory leak would happen, but that doesn't mean it won't.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I _think_ there's a language barrier here and he's asking specifically about the case where writes are synchronized and reads aren't and whether a memory leak can occur in that situations.  My guess is it's homework.

Comment: Because you do the get without any form of synchronization, you have a data race on your hands. I would not even bother with reasoning about potential memory leaks if there is a known data race.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself, I'm writing it down to share.

Below code is part of LinkedHashMap

```
    public V get(Object key) {
        Node<K,V> e;
        if ((e = getNode(hash(key), key)) == null)
            return null;
        if (accessOrder)
            afterNodeAccess(e);
        return e.value;
    }

    void afterNodeAccess(Node<K,V> e) { // move node to last
        LinkedHashMap.Entry<K,V> last;
        if (accessOrder && (last = tail) != e) {
            LinkedHashMap.Entry<K,V> p =
                (LinkedHashMap.Entry<K,V>)e, b = p.before, a = p.after;
            p.after = null;
            if (b == null)
                head = a;
            else
                b.after = a;
            if (a != null)
                a.before = b;
            else
                last = b;
            if (last == null)
                head = p;
            else {
                p.before = last;
                last.after = p;
            }
            tail = p;
            ++modCount;
        }
    }
```

In the case of LinkedHashMap, if you do not use synchronized, problems may arise if you do not use synchronized because the reference values of before and after are changed when reading.
In fact, I was wondering if there is a problem when reading from various types of Maps, and I wondered if there could be a memory leak problem in reading depending on the implementation of Map.